# Slider with default functionality

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am trying to create a slider like this example.  pls anyone help me. http://devsandbox.nfshost.com/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/demos/slider/constraints.html

```
<link type="text/css" href="ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.slider.js"></script> 
<link type="text/css" href="demos.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css"> 
    #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; };
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var updateTime = function() {
    var time = $("#slider-constraints").slider("value");
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var seconds = time % 60;
    var secondsStr = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + Math.round(seconds);
    $("#amount").val(minutes+":"+secondsStr);
}
$(function() {
    $("#slider-constraints").slider({
        max: 253,
        value: 10,
        minConstraint: 10,
        maxConstraint: 10,
        enforceConstraints: false,
        slide: updateTime 
    });
    updateTime();
    var maxConstraint = 10;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        maxConstraint += 1;
        $('#slider-constraints').slider("constraints", [10, maxConstraint]);
    }, 300);
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('#slider-constraints').slider("value", $('#slider-constraints').slider("value")+1);
        updateTime();
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Problem:

1. I want to remove the progress bar.
2. Fill the handle covered position with other color

Geetha.

Comment: put some code to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by #2, but to remote the progress bar, shorten all that code down to this:

```
$("#slider-constraints").slider({
    max: 253,
    value: 10,
    minConstraint: 10,
    maxConstraint: 253,
    enforceConstraints: false
});
```

Just have your `maxConstraint` match your `max` to fill the bar after the cursor.  Adjust the `minConstraint` option to be where you want, the `value` will be the initial position of the slider handler, in this example code, it matches.

If by #2 you mean that you want the portion after filled at all times, just update the `minConstraint` to match the current value (where the slider's at), like this:

```
$("#slider-constraints").slider({
    max: 253,
    value: 10,
    minConstraint: 10,
    maxConstraint: 253,
    enforceConstraints: false,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#slider-constraints").slider("constraints", [ui.value, 253]);
    }
});
```